# WP - Can't style boxes or load pictures?

Tags: css, wordpress, html

At this [website](http://raad-mal.dk) i need to add links to google+ and Facebook. I can't get the CSS i make effect the div boxes. I have also tried to add the pictures with an img tag, but i can't load the pictures even though it seem to be the right directory and the other images have the same directory.
I want to add the 2 icons to the right side on the menu bar.

HTML:

```
<div class="art-nav">
    <ul class="art-menu">
        <?php art_menu_items(); ?>
    </ul>
    <div id="facebooktopmarc">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/raadmal">
            <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Go to Facebook!"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="googleplustopmarc">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
            <img src="images/google-plus.png" alt="Go to Google-plus!"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#facebooktopmarc {
  background-image: url("images/facebook.png");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
}

#googleplustopmarc {
  background-image: url("images/google-plus.png");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urls inside CSS is related to this CSS file position in filesystem. If you want to use img inside html, you should use path relative to this html or absolute paths with domain name.

Your images have urls

```
http://raad-mal.dk/wp-content/themes/green_room/images/facebook.png
http://raad-mal.dk/wp-content/themes/green_room/images/google-plus.png
```

Comment: Thx now I got the images to show, but I still can't style the div, so I can't move them up on the menu bar. Any thoughts on this? :)

Comment: I cant find #facebooktopmarc and #googleplustopmarc in css on http://raad-mal.dk/. Are you sure it is already there?

Comment: Ahh I had been working in my backup and uploading the original one. Silly me. Thx a lot for the help :)